# sql query to modify the selected value from database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table number(int value).
If i want to add or subtract a value, how should i proceed?
ex: value is 30.
I want to subtract 7 to make it 23.
What should the query look like?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Also, is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: **Research**, then ask...

Comment: If you want to update the table values, do UPDATE. If you just want to subtract while reading, do a SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table1 set numberfield = numberfield - 7
```

if numberfield is 30, then numberfield = 30 - 7, difference will be the new value of the field